# Linux command line partition manager with LVM

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I need to write a program to format SD card with, FAT boot, ext4 and swap partitions.
I would like the ext4 to use LVM. Ideally there would be scope for mdadm.

I need help finding a command line utity which is capable of all this.
I will be able to control any command from within my program. Would rather not cut & paste source.

I understand that Gparted does not cope well with LVM.
Any suggestions for a better command?

Comment: Do you tried parted?
It is the same as gparted, but in command line

Comment: There are various command-line utilities that achieve each of the steps. Why is it that you require them all in a single one?

Answer (score 0):

sfdisk - cli partitioning 
pvcgreate, lvcreate, lvchange, lvresize - create and manage LVM volumes

You don't need a specific tool to manage LVM partitions because once a logical volume has been created, it looks like any other block device (hard-drive, sdcard, etc).